# Ansible: Print debug msg with different color

Tags: ansible

We have task which is writing out the deprecated messages and we would like to highlight it somehow to give greater importance these messages for user.

Is it possibility to change color of msg parameter of ansible debug module? Or have you another solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can control the Ansible output with configuration parameters. Check if setting [ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/config.html#ansible-force-color) to true gives you the wished results. Colorized output needs to be supported by the tty as well.

Ansible seems to offer some more parameters related to colorized output. Search for "color" in the [configuration options documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/config.html)

The color for `deprecation` warning is controled by `COLOR_DEPRECATE` which defaults tp `purple`. So in theory Ansible should print deprecation warnings in purple color as long as `ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR` parameter is left with its default value of `false`.

Comment: Thank you for inspirations, but we found the different solution. We used the shell module and formatted its output. `shell: echo -e "\033[35mHello World\e[0m"`

Comment: That should work as well. Updated my answer a bit and there is parameter to control the colorizing of deprecation warning.

Comment: Hmm, thank you for a more detailed description, maybe we will use it once time.